# Why does my video only play sound and no video with ARJS?

Tags: video, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js, artoolkit

I'm building an Augmented Reality app with ARJS. I'm using an image as a marker and it seems to be working. The goal is to play a video when the image tracker detects the correct image, however, it plays only the audio and not the whole video.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="./js/image-tracker/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/image-tracker/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('controller', {
        init: function() {
          this.toggle = false;
          this.video = document.querySelector('#video');
          this.video.pause();
        },

        tick: function() {
          if (this.el.object3D.visible === true) {
            if (!this.toggle) {
              this.toggle = true;
              this.video.play();
            }
          } else {
            this.toggle = false;
            this.video.pause();
          }
        }
      })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
  <a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
    renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
    embedded
    arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;"
  >
    <a-assets>
      <video id="video" src="http://localhost:5000/assets/animation.mp4" webkit-playsinline playsinline></video>
    </a-assets>

    <a-nft
      controller
      type="nft"
      url="./image_descriptors/car"
      smooth="true"
      smoothCount="10"
      smoothTolerance="0.01"
      smoothThreshold="5"
    >
      <a-video
        width="1.75"
        height="2"
        position="200 0 -10"
        rotation="0 90 0"
        src="#video"
      ></a-video>
    </a-nft>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The video is paused, or it isn't anywhere?

Comment: Hi, the video is being served from my node express server locally. As you can see on the above script the video is reproduced when I point the image and pause when I stop to point the image. This logic is working. I'm able to listen to the video's audio, but not able to see the video.

Comment: If You're hitting a wall, I've got a couple ideas - 1) Put a box / sphere at the same location and check if its visible (you'll hear it even if its too small to see, or out of the camera view) 2) mobile will probably need user interaction for a video to play.

Comment: also you could try it out with a normal marker / vanilla a-frame to rule out if it's related to arjs or not

Comment: I created a brand new project only with the scene and a box. It worked, however, when I put a <a-nft> marker, and grabbed the box inside the marker, it stops to work. It seems something has to do with position. Outside the marker I have to put a position "0 0 -3" to see the box.

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski, I tested with a marker hiro and it works fine (audio and video), however, when I change to a  <a-nft> I can only hear the audio, not video neither box.

Comment: my guess is the video and the box are somewhere outside of the camera view. Not sure how to properly debug it, is there any chance you'd create a [giltch](https://glitch.com/) with the nft marker + image?

Comment: Hi @PiotrAdamMilewski, I have a guess of what might be happening. I think the camera is disaligned. For some reason, the aframe camera is shifted up and left. You can check this codesandbox (in a device you can notice this effect). https://codesandbox.io/s/arjs-example-forked-6qd93?file=/public/index.html

Comment: Any chance You'd also upload the images there? I think there are only the videos + image descriptors

Comment: It's no need to upload the image, only the three descriptors files, and the video.

Comment: I can't try it out without the images. Or i can try using other ones with other descriptors

Comment: Hey, Piotr, I put an image there for you `https://6qd93.sse.codesandbox.io/descriptors/car.jpeg`. You capture it with your phone to test. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons, here are some of them:

1. Make sure there are no console errors and the scene loads properly (your sandbox gave me `out of memory!!!` issues, also there were some CORS issues).
2. Make sure that the video is placed on top of the marker. I'd use an oversized box (or the inspector) to find out where is the item, and adjust the position / scale.

I've made NFT descriptors with your `car.jpg` resized to 1024x1024, and it seems to be working [link to the forked sandbox with new descriptors](https://codesandbox.io/s/arjs-nft-stack7011381-ct8sd?file=/public/index.html) :

[image]